# ember 2.17: calling a jquery document.ready() function

Tags: ember.js

I am really new to Ember, which I am asked to do and well, love to learn. Basically, the current project uses [Gentelella Admin Dashboard](https://themewagon.com/themes/free-bootstrap-3-admin-dashboard-template/). I being trying to get the dashboard to load properly but failed.

After I login, I get redirected to /dashboard/ route, which basically loads the main dashboard interface. Now the problem is I can't click-expand the menus on the sidebar nor toggle the sidebar menu. And the main page is not extended to fill the space, as in our current application.

I know the function init_start() takes care of the resize and the click, which is already added to vendor.js from custom.js but I can't seem to call the function from ember at all.

My latest attempt was using mixins but it failed too:

```
             import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  activate: function() {
    this._super();
    init_sidebar();

  }
});
```

then from dashboard.js route:

```
        import HandleTempLoadMixin from '../mixins/handle-temp-load';
        export default Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin,HandleTempLoadMixin, {
```

});

but still the function is not executed.

I have read that it is best to avoid working with jquery inside ember in SO but I have pretty much many JQuery functions that I cant transfer right now (nor sure why exactly since it says somewhere in the documentation jquery is built into ember itself).

Anyway, what is the best way to initailize the dashboard interface?

Comment: How did you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you have some `jQuery` stuff that you would like to utilise. I suggest looking into Component's `didInsertElement` hook and triggering your custom code from there.

You can find more details in here https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.17.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_integrating-with-third-party-libraries-with-code-didinsertelement-code

In general, try avoid working with view related stuff in `Route`s. Ember's power comes from strong conventions. Learning where to place your code is crucial.

Comment: Thanks @Denzo. I did try ddInsertElement with run loop but I failed to call the function. I don't expect to write the contents of the init_sidebar() function inside didInsertElement, right? That would mean copy paste codes in multiple places instead of calling functions. Unless i am wrong somewhere.

Comment: It depends on where your `init_sidebar` lives. I would assume you have some js script files. If that is the case, you'll have to place it in the `vendor` folder of your project. And then include it in your build in order for it to be included in your app. You can learn more about managing dependencies here https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.17.0/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/